# Pyter not working when written as a Python Program

Tags: python-2.7, bleu

I am using pyter API for finding translational error rate(TER) between two words. Pyter normally works in terminal, but when I am using it in Python code, it isn’t working. Normally, it works by writing pyter.ter(w1,w2), but now it is saying that pyter module has no attribute "ter".

Comment: Could You please post the code in question and full error message?

Answer (score 0):

actually it got solved. BY mistake I was saving the program named as pyter.py. So, whenever I was importing pyter, the error message of the actual program was being shown. I renamed the script as pyter_xyz.py, and its running fine.

Thanks for the concern @Kamiccolo